# Codeigniter on Azure webconfig

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I deployed the old website based on CodeIgniter 2.x on to the Azure web app.

I changed base url, however except for the main webpage, other don't work, it says doesn't exist.

I've found that we have to have web.config instead of .htaccess as well.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

here is the code that I've got from the old website .htaccess instead of this what should I write down into web.config for Azure?

Comment: Have you tried moving the Rewrite rules out of `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>`?

Comment: @Goose oh I haven't tried let me try it thx

Comment: Did moving the rewrite rules work?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this `web.config` template https://gist.github.com/wmandai/d28cc45f10a19eec0fcb